# sql query to retrieve min to max date and their corresponding values to separate Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and need help to write a script to find which drugs were prescripted from the start of the consultation for that particular Customer ID and display it in separate columns. Basically i need to find out the min(dates) and get its corresponding value(drug) and display it in a separate column as `FIRSTDRUG`, etc.

**Table structure:**

```
ID      DATES         VALUE
---------------------------
111     12/01/2015    DRUG3
111     24/01/2015    DRUG1
111     01/01/2015    DRUG5
```

**Desired output:**

```
ID    FIRSTDRUG   SECONDDRUG  THRIDDRUG
---------------------------------------
111   DRUG5       DRUG3       DRUG1
```

Any help will be sincerely appreciated, many thanks

Comment: Does every ID always have three drugs?

Comment: Hi Tab Alleman, not always, sometimes there is only one drug and in that case it should display NULL under corresponding seconddrug, thriddrug fields. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it from your comment that an ID may have less than, but never more than three drugs.

In that case, this is one way to get your desired output:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT [ID], [VALUE], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By [ID], Order By [Dates] ASC) AS RN
)
SELECT [ID], 
MAX(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN [VALUE] ELSE NULL END) AS FirstDrug,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN=2 THEN [VALUE] ELSE NULL END) AS SecondDrug,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN=3 THEN [VALUE] ELSE NULL END) AS ThirdDrug
FROM cte
GROUP BY [ID]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tab Alleman. It works perfect. Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough as i'm new to this site and SQL. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a derived table form:

```
select T.id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN T.ord = 1 then T.value else '' end) as FIRST_DRUG,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T.ord = 2 then T.value else '' end) as SECOND_DRUG,
       MAX(CASE WHEN T.ord = 3 then T.value else '' end) as THIRD_DRUG
from (select *,  RANK() OVER(partition by id  order by dates asc) as ord from medic) as T
group by T.id
```

Just go appending lines for the fourth, fifth, and so on, drugs for as many as you need.